# How do I count the number of lines in a text file?

Tags: python

For python I have an assignment where I have to calculate the number of words in the text file and display the average number of words per sentence. However the average number of words turns up on always becoming one.

The text file is

```
Hello
How are you
I am fine 
Have a good day 
Bye
```

Here is the code

```
def main():
    num_words = 0
    total_words = 0
    total_lines = 0

    in_file = open("text.txt", "r")

    line = in_file.readline()

    while line != "":
        num_words = 0
        num_lines = 0
        line_list = line.split()

        for word in line_list:
            num_words = num_words + 1

        for line in line_list:
            num_lines = num_lines + 1

        total_words = total_words + num_words 

        total_lines = total_lines + num_lines
        average = total_words / total_lines
        line = in_file.readline()

    print "Total words: ", total_words
    print "Average number of words per sentence: ", average

    in_file.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better way to do this would be the following:

```
f = open('in_file.dat')

num_lines = 0
tot_words = 0

for line in f:
    num_lines += 1
    tot_words += len(line.split())

average = tot_words / num_lines

print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for line in line_list:
        num_lines = num_lines + 1
```

^ that's wrong.  `line_list` is the words - you're adding one "line" for every word, instead of just once per line. There should only be one `num_lines = num_lines + 1` inside your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this is homework, I will only give hints.

What does split do?
What does "for x in y:" do?

Make sure you're counting words and lines correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to determine the average number of words per *sentence*. Sentences are terminated by a full stop/period character (and others such as a question mark) and can span lines, or there can be multiple sentences on one line. It might be the case that your sample data is all you need to handle, in which case your assumption that there is one sentence per line is true. If it's not then you need to treat `'.'`, `'?'` etc. specially.

Addressing the specific problem, the average comes out as 1 because `total_lines` and `total_words` will always be the same. This is because lines and words are treated equivalently.

You don't need this code because it is actually counting words, not lines:

```
for line in line_list:
    num_lines = num_lines + 1
```

And you can change

```
total_lines = total_lines + num_lines
```

to

```
total_lines = total_lines + 1
```

Also, as you are using Python 2, the average calculation will use integer division, i.e. it will truncate the result. You can force floating point division by casting one of the values to a float:

```
average = float(total_words) / total_lines
```